# Creating a websocket for an android MMO using Unity3d and Node.js

Tags: android, node.js, unity-game-engine, websocket, mmo

I'm developing an android MMO android game in free version of Unity. I have node.js installed on my pc. should i use the following server-client side code because when i tried to test it i could get the server side script running but couldn't figure out whether the client is connecting or not. Also when i tried to build the apk, unity gives an error saying "using System.Net.Sockets requires pro version of unity." Please help!!

**server side**  (on node.js)

```
`var net = require('net');
var tcp_server = net.createServer(function(socket)
{

    socket.write('hello\n');
    socket.end('world\n');
});
tcp_server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server Running...");`
```

**client side (in unity c# script)**

```
`using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
public class tcpClient : MonoBehaviour 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.Log("start");
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8000);
        Debug.Log ("Connected");
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        bytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
            // Read up to 4096 bytes
            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
        }
        catch
        {
            /*a socket error has occured*/
        }
        //We have read the message.
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Debug.Log(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
        //Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use socket.io

http://socket.io/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to use native socket you need Unity3D Pro.

But there are another ways to handle this problem.

You can use one of them. You can find them in Unity Asset Store.(I know these maybe more than these assets). (They are not free but cheaper than Unity pro).

1. [Good ol' Sockets](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13166)
2. [Best HTTP Basic](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10765)
3. [Best HTTP Pro Edition](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10872)

After that @ploutch mention [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/). It's really good.

But don't forget Unity3D has it's own [Network](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.html). You can create server also join client with using it. Also some providers which are really good and gives extra options to you.

Like:

1. [Photon Unity Networking](https://www.exitgames.com/en/PUN)
2. [Bolt Networking Middleware](http://www.boltengine.com/)